# Custom add-on not appearing in Add-On Manager

Tags: add-on-development, ee3

I've created a barebones add-on directory structure, but ExpressionEngine will not list it. The only file that I've included, addon.setup.php, is defined as follows:

```
return array(
      'author' => 'h',
      'author_url' => 'j',
      'name' => 'name',
      'description' => 'desc',
      'version' => 'version',
      'namespace' => 'ns',
      'settings_exist' => false
);
```

While that is obviously junk, that is a well-formed array, providing EE with all the fields it is expecting. It is in the directory **system/user/addons/wmd_cp**. I have enabled debugging in **admin.php**, but no issues are being displayed.

At this point, I don't understand why EE will not acknowledge this add-on's existence. For what it is worth, I have other add-ons in the directory (some third party, some I have written myself) and they display correctly. I have also matched this folder's permissions and ownership with that of the working add-ons. EE's path settings are pointing at the correct directories.

I would appreciate any insight. What have I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also have a pi.wmd_cp.php, ext.wmd_cp.php or mod.wmd_cp.php files with a class that matches your folder name. Otherwise, EE has no way of knowing what the addon is.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! This module would only add a control panel interface, and not provide any front end functionality, so I did not think EE would require me to include a mod file that would largely go unused.